# Returning 'still loading' response with Flask API

Tags: python, flask, scikit-learn, gunicorn

I have a [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/) classifier running as a [Dockerised](https://www.docker.com/) [Flask app](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/api/#), launched with [gunicorn](https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/). It receives input data in JSON format as a POST request, and responds with a JSON object of results.

When the app is first launched with gunicorn, a large model ([serialised with joblib](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html)) is read from a database, and loaded into memory before the app is ready for requests. This can take 10-15 minutes.

A reproducible example isn't feasible, but the basic structure is illustrated below:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response
import joblib
import json

def classifier_app(model_name):
    # Line below takes 10-15 mins to complete
    classifier = _load_model(model_name)
    app = Flask(__name__)

    @app.route('/classify_invoice', methods=['POST'])
    def apicall():
        query = request.get_json()
        results = _build_results(query['data'])
        return Response(response=results,
                        status=200,
                        mimetype='application/json')

    print('App loaded!')
    return app
```

How do I configure Flask or gunicorn to return a 'still loading' response (or suitable error message) to any incoming http requests while `_load_model` is still running?

Comment: Do you want to create a progress-bar or something?

Comment: You can use Celery to handle the joblib task asynchronously. You'll also need to install a broker such as RabbitMQ or Redis that will serve as a task queue

Comment: @Montreal no progress bar - just an http response to a POST request.

Comment: @prithajnath this sounds interesting, but could you explain how it resolves the problem? The app is created while the joblib task runs, and then if a request comes in before the model exists, we can return an error?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to return two responses for one request. So there are two different possibilities.

First one is to run time-consuming task in background and ping server with simple ajax requests every two seconds to check if task is completed or not. If task is completed, return result, if not, return `"Please standby"` string or something.

Second one is to use websockets and flask-socketio extension.

Basic server code would be something like this:

```
from threading import Thread
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
socketio = SocketIO(app)

def do_work():
    result = your_heavy_function()
    socketio.emit("result", {"result": result}, namespace="/test/")

@app.route("/api/", methods=["POST"])
def start():
    socketio.start_background_task(target=do_work)
    # return intermediate response
    return Response()
```

On the client side you should do something like this

```
var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + '/test/');
socket.on('result', function(msg) {
    // Process your request here
});
```

For further details, visit [this blog post](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent), [flask-socketio documentation](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for server-side reference and [socketio documentation](https://socket.io/docs/client-api/) for client-side reference.

**PS** Using web-sockets this you can make progress-bar too.